# Erlang: Why is greater-equal(=>) written as (>=)?

Tags: syntax, erlang, comparator

In Erlang, using `=>` to compare two variables results in a syntax error, you have to use `>=` instead:

```
1> 10 => 5.
* 1: syntax error before: '>'
2> 10 >= 5.
true
```

Why is that? The same applies for `<=` which has to be written as `=<`. Is this because Erlang always used this syntax, or are the sequences `=>` and `>=` used somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably just an Erlang convention.  The reason I'd guess would be to do with how we pronounce these symbols: "greater than or equal to", "less than or equal to".  It's really a rendering of the greater-than-or-equal-to/less-than-or-equal-to symbol in ASCII, so at some point someone decided the token should be `<=` and `>=`, and the convention has stuck in most languages, but it's fairly arbitrary.  Perhaps they were attempting to create some kind of representation of the asymmetric nature of these operators.

It's also worth noting that lots of languages use `=>` to mean some kind of arrow, such as separating the body of a function from its arguments, or as logical entailment.  Not sure about the converse one.

EDIT:  It appears that Erlang uses `<=` in comprehensions, which is why they've avoided using it as a comparison operator, and opted for the (slightly backwards) syntax instead.

Comment: How can one use `<=` in comprehension? I only know of using `<-`: `[ X || X <- [1,2,3,4]]`.

Comment: I'm really not an Erlang programmer, but there is a section in the language spec about "binary comprehensions" that uses this syntax.  It appears to provide different semantics to using `<-`.

Comment: You are right. Documentation can be found here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79300

Answer (score 6):

Just to confirm what others have said: we used the same comparison operators as Prolog. I can't be certain why it does it this way but one reason could be that it leaves `<=` and `=>` to be used as "arrows", which could be useful. In Prolog it is very easy to define new operators so even if they are not defined in the basic language they are still very useful:

```
:- op(Priority, Type, Operator).
```

The `<=` operator in in Erlang is a binary generator which can be used in list/binary comprehensions. It works in a similar way to `<-` but on binaries instead of lists.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Erlang's syntax is influenced by Prolog's and Prolog uses the same convention so that's probably the reason.

I am not sure why Prolog uses `>=` and `=<`; `=>` and `<=` are not really used. I assume that it's because `=>` and `<=` are operators typically used for the logical implication so it is indeed awkward to use them for comparison, especially in a logic programming language. It is also prettier imho :b

Comment: I didn't think of comparing this to Prolog before. But this makes sense. I haven't encountered `=>` or `<=` in Prolog, are they used for anything or just a syntactical error?

Comment: @envu nope, they are not default operators. the first erlang vm was implemented in prolog so it kinda makes sense XD